# React App won't run- after accidentaly run npm add -syntax error: 'import' and 'export'

Tags: reactjs, import, compiler-errors

I am getting this error below on my react project. I looked everywhere and try anything to resolve this but still not succesful. this happen right after I accidentally did npm add instead on git add.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I attached a pic of the error.[image]

Failed to compile.

Error in ./src/reportWebVitals.js
Syntax error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (4:4)

Comment: have you got a link to your repor ?

Comment: https://github.com/yvens47/quickr